# Switching Mars DEM elevation values from negative to positive?

Tags: dem, raster-calculator, mars

I'm using a DEM of Mars I got from UA's HiRISE website, and I want to convert it into an STL for 3D printing using the DEMto3D plugin.

However, the raster values are all negative, so I thought I could convert them into positive values using the Raster Calculator. Any time I try this though, I get an error message saying that "Raster calculator : Could not create destination file."

I haven't had this problem before working with HiRISE DEMs on QGIS, so I uninstalled and reinstalled the program, but that didn't work.

This is the link from which I got the DEM: https://www.uahirise.org/dtm/dtm.php?ID=ESP_027802_1685

Comment: Turns out that the DEMto3D plugin worked fine even with the negative values, guess I don't need to use raster calculator at all.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! If you have found the solution, for sharing, please answer your own question, it's a good practice here ! And after two days, check it as a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Previously, the plug in didn't seem to accept negative elevation values, so I tried to use the Raster Calculator as per [this answer about Mars DEMs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321050/switching-mars-dem-elevation-values-from-negative-to-positive?noredirect=1#comment522428_321050), but more recently it turns out that the plugin will work just fine with negative elevation values.